# Google visualization api on app engine not working... (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-visualization

I'm trying to render the sortable table that's provided in Google visualization API in my app on app engine, but it's not working. The app is written in python and uses the django framework.

When I copy the generated HTML/Javascript and save it as a plain html file locally, it works just fine. This leads me to believe that the problem is that http://www.google.com/jsapi'> is not getting included or is not able to run.

Anyone else run into this? Am I missing some configuration piece in app.yaml?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the HTML that is being produced:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
 <head>
   <title> 
      Test
   </title> 
   <link href="/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Nickname');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Target');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Recording');
        data.addRows(2);

        data.setCell(0, 0, '0987654321');

    data.setCell(0, 1, 'Active');

        data.setCell(0, 2, 'Nothing');
        data.setCell(0, 3, '1234567890');

    data.setCell(0, 4, 'Enabled');

    data.setCell(1, 0, '0987654321');

    data.setCell(1, 1, 'Active');

        data.setCell(1, 2, 'Nothing');
        data.setCell(1, 3, '1234567890');

    data.setCell(1, 4, 'Enabled');


       var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
       table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }
    </script> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
    <div id='table_div'></div> 
 </body> 
</html>
```

This works fine if saved as an html file.

```
app.yaml:

application: testapp
version: 2
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(mp3|wav))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(mp3|wav))

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

Comment: Seriously, how would we know? We don't know what your app.yaml looks like, nor the HTML/JS. I think you have to give us something to look at so we can help you. Also, are you talking about the development server or a deployed application?

Comment: Other things that would help make the question answerable would be what you mean by "not working."  what do you see on the screen?

Comment: balpha: Nice.... rude comment and no help... maybe you shouldn't waste your time posting if you don't have anything useful to say.

Comment: Peter:
The app is deployed, but same issue when run on the sdk. The screen renders everything except the table. View source shows proper javascript generated and everything works fine if I save the source as a page and view it.

While I am pretty new at the python/app engine, I usually pick things up quickly. If there is a tutorial you know of for the visualization api and app engine (python or java), I'd be happy to just go there. Thanks!

Comment: Dear Sologoub: I'm sorry that my comment appears rude to you, because it definitely wasn't meant to be (which part of my comment do you see as rude?). All I did was try to explain to you why with the current level of information you're providing it's not possible to help you. There are lots of pepople here that always try to be helpful, but you have to give us something to work with. I put this comment because I *wanted* to help you. You write "Am I missing some configuration piece in app.yaml?" There are probably some people here that could answer this -- *if they saw* your app.yaml.

Comment: There's nothing rude about the first comment - you're asking for help with a technical subject with no information other than "it doesn't work". That would require psychic debugging. Please *post your code* along with any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Thanks, balpha... guess I'm being overly sensitive, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue - I messed up headers of the page generated by rendering with the same function I created for XML output.

Including this killed it: handler.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml"

Answer (score 0):

Wait, where are you doing the rendering?  The visapi stuff goes in the client-side.  Is that where you have it?  (Sorry if that's obvious; it's really not entirely clear from the way you wrote the question.)

More details would definitely help.

Comment: Thank you, and yeah, it's in the client-side.

I've posted the html and the app.yaml. I'm 99% sure that the issue is with either app.yaml or with including a remote javascript.

Comment: I never had to do *anything* to app.yaml to get these to work. FWIW.

Comment: Ah, and now I've had a chance to look at your generated code.  Your problem is your code.  I think you're confusing "works on the generated html" for "works by accident when exactly the right things happen in the right order."  If you fix that, it'll work from the appengine, too.

Comment: LH, sorry for noobishness, but can you elaborate?