# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<a Document> has no method 'write'?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When trying to include google visualization api into a page on google app engine, getting this error in the developer tools console in Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'write'

In FF 3.5 the error is "n.write is not a function". A bit of a noob here and have no clue how to troubleshoot this. Any ideas?

Code can be found here:
[Google visualization api on app engine not working... (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290827/google-visualization-api-on-app-engine-not-working-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has this issue - I messed up headers of the page generated by rendering with the same function I created for XML output.

Including this killed it: handler.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml"

Comment: yep, this is bull shit, google doesn't want you to serve the document as `application/xhtml+xml`?

Comment: not sure if it's Google or not, but what I'm guessing is happening is that javascript that it's trying to execute cannot be run when document is supposed to be a plain text or xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSF2 and XHTML facelets, you need to use:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
   <!-- page with charts here -->
</f:view>
```